# Is it valid to perform PCA if Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin (KMO) index is very low?

Tags: pca

I have a dataset that contains data from $307$ subjects and nine variables for each subject. I would like to run a PCA. My problem is that I get a Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin (KMO) value of $0.06$.

Can it be due to the fact that within every subject the variables add up to $1$? Is there another way to test whether it is okay to run PCA on my data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the variables sum up to a constant exactly, the correlation or covariance matrix is singular and therefore no Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin (KMO) index can be computed from it. In your case, I suspect, the sum is almost a constant, and KMO was able to compute but it is naturally very low.

PCA can be done with such data as yours. KMO is relevant in the context of [Factor analysis, not PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38709/skewed-variables-in-factor-analysis/38714#38714), though. As for FA, some extraction methods can process singular matrix but others cannot. PCA - you can do it on any numeric data, even it does not make sense at all.