KMO measure in principal component analysis
I just started to be interested in PCA. I have a data set of 21 variables with 27 samples, and I am trying to make an application in Jamovi with this data set. I performed KMO and Bartlett's test before PCA analysis. There is no problem in Bartlett's test, but the KMO value was measured as 0.51. To make KMO more reasonable, I removed 5 variables from the data set and this value increased (up to 0.76). But I did this by trial and error. Looking at the correlation matrix I then examined the variables but could not find a pattern. How can I do this logically? I didn't quite understand how I could eliminate variables for PCA. Can you help me?

kmo .5 is not very bad. Kmo is used mostly in factor analysis model, not in PCA.

Check this also please https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/229244/3277
